# Node-red app in Bluemix crashes when performance testing

Tags: ibm-cloud, mq, cloudant, node-red

I have a node-red app in Bluemix that contains 2 flows.

The first flow has  3 nodes: an Http In node, a function that reformats from 1 json object to another and an Mqlight node.

The 2nd flow has an mqlignt input, a batcher node to batch so many messages together, a couple nodes to reformat and then an http request node to put the message to a cloudant database.

I have been trying to performance test this.  I feed it 1000-5000 messages over a few minutes and it crashes before all the messages are put to the database.  The error just says exit status 255: CRASHED.  I do not see any additional data in the logs.

Any help would be appreciated.

See attached screen prints. 
Memory usage:  353MB/1.625GB
Disk usage:    333MB/1GB
CPU:  .3%

[image: Memory]

[CRASH ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3K92P.png)  UPDATED 4/4/2016 with the error from the crash

Comment: How much ram have you given the app and can you post the end of the log even if it doesn't appear to show much. Edit the question to answer this, don't try and add them as a comment

Comment: Rather than use the online log viewer run `cf logs <app name>` and stream it to a file while it runs the test. This will show you all the log history in a way that is easier to search for the real error.

Comment: We would probably want to see more details of your actual flow as well to understand which specific nodes you're using. We know, for example, the Function node is relatively expensive and should be avoided if possible when throughout and performance are important.

Comment: Updated the problem description with the crash error.  Please let me know what other information I can provide.

Comment: Also, I just tried combining the 2 flows thereby removed the MqLight nodes.  I have not crashed since I did this.  Still testing though to verify this.  Are there any known problems with the MqLight nodes related to volume?

Comment: 1000-5000 messages over a couple of minutes shouldn't cause any problems to the MQ Light client. Can you strip out the HTTP/Cloudant parts of the flow and just use an inject node with a timer to put 2-3000 messages per minute to MQ Light in the 1st flow, get them in the 2nd flow and just discard them, to check MQ Light can handle that number? Like I say it should be able to fine.

Comment: @Matthew Whitehead I created a flow in Node-red that just has an MQ Light input node and a function to print to the console.  I ran a java app to put 5000 messages to the MQ Light topic.  The node-red flow ran without a problem.  I tried again & the node-red app started to process messages but then failed with an error - see next 2 comments for the error (it is too long to add here)

Comment: @Matthew Whitehead Error received: node-red: ../src/node.cc:1052: v8::Handle<v8::Value> node::MakeCallback(node::Environment*, v8::Handle<v8::Value>, v8::Handle<v8::Function>, int, v8::Handle<v8::Value>*): Assertion `env->context() == env->isolate()->GetCurrentContext()' failed.
App instance exited with guid 434f636f-39b2-4550-886e-f68e65510cf7 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"434f636f-39b2-4550-886e-f68e65510cf7", "version"=>"28d1910d-fcca-4c9e-9f3d-c842f98e658e", "instance"=>"34012353cced428eb7582c5d05e17b04", "index"=>0,

Comment: @Matthew Whitehead "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>255, "exit_description"=>"app instance exited", "crash_timestamp"=>1460138869}
Starting app instance (index 0) with guid 434f636f-39b2-4550-886e-f68e65510cf7

Comment: @jd76 I don't recognise that error message - it doesn't look related to MQ Light.

Comment: @knolleary have you seen this before in node-red?

Comment: @MatthewWhitehead no I haven't - a crash in v8 suggests an issue with a module with a native code component. What version of node.js etc is this?